# Proof of integral equality

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $f^{(n)}(x)$ be the $n$-th derivative of $f(x) = \cos(x)$. Prove that :

$$
\int_0^{2\pi} f^{(n)}(x) \,\, dx = \int_0^{2\pi} f^{(n)}(kx) \,\, dx,
$$
where $n$, $k$ are natural numbers equal or greater than 1.

Any ideas?  Some help would be really appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the derivatives $f^{(n)}$ with $n$ odd are $\pm\sin$, and
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(kx)\,dx=\left.-{\cos kx\over k}\right]_{x=0}^{x= 2\pi}=0.$$
The calculations for $n$ even are similar.